# custom directive isolate scope for multiple image carousels

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope

---

### The issue

I would like to have this image carousel in multiple places on the same page using the same directive. However, in it's current state, it seems as though they are sharing the same scope.

e.g

If I click the arrow icons to go to the next image, they all fire and go to their next image simultaneously. How can I avoid this?

Thanks in advance.

---

### Here's the JS

```
productDetail.directive('imageSwitcher',
    ['$rootScope', '$resource', '$timeout', 'app_settings', 'mainConfig',
    function($rootScope, $resource, $timeout, app_settings, mainConfig) {

        var gridData = {
            imgCount : 0,
            currentImage : 0,
            nextImage : 1,
            prevImage : 1
        }

        var actions = {
        setCurrentImage : function(ind) {
            gridData.currentImage = ind > (gridData.imgCount - 1)
                ? 0
                : ind < 0
                    ? (gridData.imgCount - 1)
                    : ind;

            gridData.nextImage = (gridData.currentImage + 1) > (gridData.imgCount - 1)
                ? 0
                : (gridData.currentImage + 1) < 0
                    ? (gridData.imgCount - 1)
                    : (gridData.currentImage + 1);

            gridData.prevImage = (gridData.currentImage - 1) > (gridData.imgCount - 1)
                ? 0
                : (gridData.currentImage - 1) < 0
                    ? (gridData.imgCount - 1)
                    : (gridData.currentImage - 1);
        }
    }

    return {
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: '/image-switcher.html',
        scope : {
            pr : '=imageSwitcher'
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.actions = actions;
            scope.gridData = gridData;
            scope.locale = locale;
            gridData.imgCount = scope.pr.prodData.productImageUrls.imgArray.length;

            var resetImageData = function() {
                gridData.imgCount = scope.pr.prodData.productImageUrls.imgArray.length;
                actions.setCurrentImage(gridData.currentImage);
            };

            $rootScope.$watch('hasBrokenImages', function(){
                for (var i = 0; i < $rootScope.brokenImages.length; i++) {
                    var ind = scope.pr.prodData.productImageUrls.imgArray.indexOf($rootScope.brokenImages[i], 0);
                    if (ind > -1) {
                        scope.pr.prodData.productImageUrls.imgArray.splice(ind, 1);
                    };
                };
                resetImageData();
            })

            scope.$watch('pr.prodData.currentColorCode', function(newVal, oldVal){
                scope.$evalAsync(function(e){
                    $timeout(function() {
                        resetImageData();
                    }, 100);
                });
            });

            scope.$watch('pr.productId', function(newVal, oldVal){
                scope.actions.setCurrentImage(0)
            });
        }
    }
}]
);
```

---

### Here's the markup

```
<div image-switcher="pr">
    <div class="product-images expanded" >
    <span class="fullwidth"
        ng-click="actions.setCurrentImage((gridData.currentImage+1))">
        <img ng-src="{{ pr.prodData.productImageUrls.imgArray[gridData.currentImage]}}"
            />

    </span>
    <img ng-src="{{
            pr.prodData.productImageUrls.imgArray[gridData.nextImage]}}"
        ng-hide="true"/>
    <div class="hiddenImages" ng-hide="true">
        <img ng-src="{{
                pr.prodData.productImageUrls.imgArray[gridData.prevImage]}}"
             />
    </div>
</div>
<div style="text-align: center;" ng-show="pr.prodData.productImageUrls.imgArray.length > 1">
    <p class="img-counter">
        {{gridData.currentImage + 1}}/{{gridData.imgCount}}
    </p>
    <p>
        <a class="mini-image-switcher mis-prev icon-L_arrow"
            ng-click="actions.setCurrentImage((gridData.currentImage-1))"></a>
        <a class="mini-image-switcher mis-next icon-R_arrow"
            ng-click="actions.setCurrentImage((gridData.currentImage+1))"></a>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks not like a common scope, but you fire the events without sending some identification for which carousel it is meant to be. You have to broadcast the events with a parameter like carouselId which should also be available in directive scope and in the watchers to verify if the parameter passed to the broadcasted event is equal to the carouselId from your scope, perform the action; otherwise do nothing.

Comment: Previously I had it as on click of the arrows check to see if $(this) had a matching id of the product and if so perform the event, but that wasn't working either.

Comment: $(this) doesn't look like angular.

Comment: It isn't, but I thought that would be clearer than saying this.

Answer (score 0):

What I mean is that your event should be broadcasted like:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('previous', "myFirstCarousel");
```

you then will be able to receive the event like:

```
$scope.$on('previous', function(event, carouselName) {
  if(carouselName== $scope.currentCarouselName)
   // do what you want to do
});
```

and in the directive definition there should be

```
        pr : '=pr',
        currentCarouselName : '=carouselName'
```

and your html should be like:

```
<image-switcher pr="pr1" carouselName="myFirstCarousel">
```

In this way the scope of the directive will receive the pr1 as parameter for first directive occurence, similar the second directive should have a distincs pr2 etc. also the scope of the directive will receive as carouselName the string provided,  so you will be able to match the directives by their uniq names given in the html declaration.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'll try it out shortly.

Comment: sort of. I was generating separate scopes for them the whole time, but it still wasn't working well. However, I was doing something similar to having a carouselName and a pr attribute which allowed for the carousel arrows to be fired independently.  I think I did it correctly (as far as conventions are concerned), but I just don't like angular conventions ( or lack thereof) haha. So, I reached out. Thanks for following up though, it's appreciated.